# How to store the selected checkbox values in arraylist in android?

Tags: android

I am working on **quiz application**. For each question there are **multiple answers** and so for that I have used **checkboxes**. In each page **I am displaying single question with options** and when next button is clicked next question will be displayed. **So when multiple answers are selected by the user I need to store them in an arraylist and need to compare the selected answers with that in database.** In my code I am storing the selected value id's one by one but at a time it is storing only one value. How to store all the selected checkbox id's in my arraylist?

My Code:

```
ArrayList<String> selchkboxlist;
CheckBox[] cbs;
 cbs = new CheckBox[20];
for(k=0; k<List3.size(); k++)
 { 
     arr = List3.get(k);
     cbs[k] = new CheckBox(getContext());
     Rl.addView(cbs[k]);
         cbs[k].setText((CharSequence) arr.get(2));
         cbs[k].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));  
         cbs[k].setId(k);
         cbs[k].setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
         { 
             public void onClick(View v) 
             { 
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ; 
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                chk = Integer.toString(v.getId());
                    selchkboxlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                    selchkboxlist.add(chk);
                    Toast.makeText(Select1.this, "Selected CheckBox ID" + v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                 selchkboxlist.remove(chk);
              Toast.makeText(Select1.this, "Not selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
         }
     });
 }
```

Please help me regarding this....Thanks in Advance

Comment: May be because you are creating a new arraylist everytime... I see a "selchkboxlist = new ArrayList<String>()"  inside a for loop...

Comment: what is List3.size() please share code again.. or edit your question.. thanks

Comment: please i have face same problem what is List3.size() please share code again.. or edit your question.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the selchkboxlist before for loop....

```
ArrayList<String> selchkboxlist=new ArrayList<String>();
CheckBox[] cbs;
cbs = new CheckBox[20];
for(k=0; k<List3.size(); k++)
{ 
 arr = List3.get(k);
 cbs[k] = new CheckBox(getContext());
 Rl.addView(cbs[k]);
     cbs[k].setText((CharSequence) arr.get(2));
     cbs[k].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));  
     cbs[k].setId(k);
     cbs[k].setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
     { 
         public void onClick(View v) 
         { 
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ; 
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            chk = Integer.toString(v.getId());
                selchkboxlist.add(chk);
                Toast.makeText(Select1.this, "Selected CheckBox ID" + v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
             selchkboxlist.remove(chk);
          Toast.makeText(Select1.this, "Not selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
     }
 });
```

}

Comment: Hi thank you its working fine...But when I am trying to print my arraylist outside my onclicklistener it is displaying null...where I am going wrong?

Comment: Put a logger Log.i("chk",chk) just before your statement that adds this to the ArrayList, see if this value is null or not...

Comment: Hi in onclick method it is displaying the arraylist values but when i am trying to print outside the onclicklistener method an empty arraylist is displayed. Why is it so?

Comment: ArrayList<String> selchkboxlist=new ArrayList<String>();  Make this global

Comment: please i have face same problem what is List3.size() please share code again.. or edit your Answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

store the value in sharedPreferences and when you need again just retrieve from sharedPreferences and do your task.

i have done in my last project and its working...try man..