# getText from all TextView which created by user

Tags: android

This is my Add button code which will get the text from `AutoCompleteTextView` and list into `ListView` on each click of Add button. I am so confusing about getting text from all `TextView` which created by user.

Because I need to compare the user inputs in all `TextView`with symptoms column in database to diagnose the disease. Hope you guys can help me =)

```
private OnClickListener onClick() {
    return new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mEditText.getText().toString()));            
        }
    };
}

private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    //textView.setText("Symptom: " + text);
    textView.setText(text);
    return textView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a ArrayList where you can store all the getText() if all the text views.

Just define and initialize your arraylist before you use it.
Initialize like below

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And in createNewTextView() method  you can have the below line to add the names to arraylist

```
arrayList.add(text)
```

later you can use these arraylist for reference and get all the text entered by user

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm new in java and android so I'm still confusing. Actually my problem similiar to [link1] and [link2]. Am I need to create another class to extend the main which contain all the setter and getter method? [link1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460275/how-to-store-the-selected-checkbox-values-in-arraylist-in-android[link2]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710550/dynamically-name-objects-based-on-edittext-input

Comment: The code above create dynamically TextView in Layout when user click Add Button after enter input in EditText. In my program there is a Confirm Button to getText from all the TextView which has been created dynamically and display it into next layout. How to getText from all TextView where the TextView has no R.id._____?